# Image Measures: Correlation and Maximum Deviation measure

Tags: image, matlab, correlation

I have two imagens with differents dimensions, and i want compare those
using Correlation (in MATLAB corr2), Maximum Deviation measures How make this?

Help me please

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if one is a scaled down version of the other use:

```
B = imresize(A, [numrows numcols])
```

So they are the same size.

If it's that one is bigger than the other, just pad the image:

```
B = padarray(A, padsize)
```

Then you will be able to use the functions.

Comment: Thanks by your response, but with this method i have loss information?